# Как правильно: "в течении" или "в течение" 3 дней?

Tags: орфография, окончания

Как правильно написать «Принимать препарат в течении 3 дней» или «Принимать препарат в течение 3 дней»?

Answer (score 33):

Если "в течени..." является предлогом (и не имеет отношения ни к какой жидкости), то на конце пишется Е: *в течени**е***. Если это существительно "течение", то выбор Е/И зависит от падежа: в чём? *в течени**и*** (появились изменения), во что? *в течени**e*** (попала нефть). Поэтому правильно: "Принимать препарат в течени**e** 3 дней", т. к. "в течени**е**" — предлог.

Comment: Поясните, как «в течение» может быть предлогом? Это же два слова, второе из которых — существительное.

Comment: Дело в том, что есть так называемые производные предлоги - перешедшие из одной части речи в другую (образованные неморфологическим способом).  Определить, что данная часть речи - предлог, можно простым способом. Предлог всегда можно включить в состав вопроса. Например, "в течении - в чём? где?" , НО "в течение дня - как долго? В ТЕЧЕНИЕ какого времени? "   Поэтому, Вы совершенно правы, это были  два слова, второе из которых — существительное. А получилось одно - производный предлог.

Comment: "Еще несколько слов: в течении двадцати лет сряду, изъездил я Россию по всем направлениям" (А.С. Пушкин. Станционный смотритель)
Как это объяснить исходя из написанного?

Comment: У Пушкина так: *Еще несколько слов: **в течение** двадцати лет сряду изъездил я Россию по всем направлениям; почти все почтовые тракты мне известны; несколько поколений ямщиков мне знакомы...* (https://ilibrary.ru/text/89/p.5/index.html)

Answer (score 16):

**В течение дня** (недели, года, вообще какого-то отрезка времени)
но — **в течении реки** (потока).

Подробнее, например, [здесь](http://www.rg.ru/2010/09/02/grammatika.html).