# В течение трёх секунд. Или в течении?

Tags: орфография, предлоги, окончания

Возник спор, как правильно написать:
удерживая кнопку в течени**и** трех секунд;
удерживая кнопку в течени**е** трех секунд.

Comment: В течение трёх секунд.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос является одним из самых часто просматриваемых на сайте.
[Как правильно: "в течении" или "в течение" 3 дней?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21673/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-3-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9)

И ответ, конечно же, есть, и он бесспорен: *удерживая кнопку в течени**е** трех секунд.*

Добавлю немного поясняющей информации.
Производный отымённый предлог «в течение» употребляется всегда в паре с существительным (или счетным оборотом) форме родительного падежа и выражает временные отношения (как долго?):
в течение часа, в течение трех часов;
в течение суток, в течение трех суток;
в течение месяца, в течение трех месяцев.

Добавлю примеры из Нацкорпуса русского языка.
Все это произошло **в течение трех секунд**. [Ю. В. Трифонов. Победитель шведов (1962)]
― Кажется, в ковбойских фильмах, чтобы попасть в цель, надо **в течение трех секунд** выхватить кольт и выстрелить. [Юрий Бондарев. Берег (1975)]

Добавлю ссылку.
[В течениЕ или в течениИ (года, месяца, недели, дня)?](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/v-techenie-ili-v-techenii.html)

Answer (score 0):

удерживая кнопку в течение трех секунд

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).